# Sikuli Open JDK 11 - Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sikuli.script.Finder.<init>(Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)

Tags: selenium, maven, automation, sikuli, openjdk-11

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[ ? : ? ]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java: 62) ~[ ? : ? ]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java: 43) ~[ ? : ? ]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 566) ~[ ? : ? ]
at rogers.automation.core.execution.handlers.testcase.FunctionalTestCaseHandler.executeTestCaseMethod(FunctionalTestCaseHandler.java: 26) ~[automation - 3.2 - SNAPSHOT.jar: 3.2 - SNAPSHOT]
at rogers.automation.core.execution.handlers.testcase.TestCaseHandler.executeTestCase(TestCaseHandler.java: 685)[automation - 3.2 - SNAPSHOT.jar: 3.2 - SNAPSHOT]
at rogers.automation.core.execution.handlers.testcase.TestCaseHandler.findAndExecuteTestCase(TestCaseHandler.java: 316)[automation - 3.2 - SNAPSHOT.jar: 3.2 - SNAPSHOT]
at rogers.automation.core.execution.handlers.testcase.TestCaseHandler.execute(TestCaseHandler.java: 280)[automation - 3.2 - SNAPSHOT.jar: 3.2 - SNAPSHOT]
at rogers.automation.core.execution.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java: 57)[automation - 3.2 - SNAPSHOT.jar: 3.2 - SNAPSHOT]
at rogers.automation.core.execution.handlers.core.TestCasesTask.executeTestCases(TestCasesTask.java: 416)[automation - 3.2 - SNAPSHOT.jar: 3.2 - SNAPSHOT]
at rogers.automation.core.execution.handlers.core.TestCasesTask.executeRunContextSpecificTestCases(TestCasesTask.java: 243)[automation - 3.2 - SNAPSHOT.jar: 3.2 - SNAPSHOT]
at rogers.automation.core.execution.handlers.core.TestCasesTask.startExecution(TestCasesTask.java: 2130)[automation - 3.2 - SNAPSHOT.jar: 3.2 - SNAPSHOT]
at rogers.automation.core.execution.handlers.core.TestCasesTask.run(TestCasesTask.java: 228)[automation - 3.2 - SNAPSHOT.jar: 3.2 - SNAPSHOT]
at rogers.automation.core.execution.handlers.core.TestCasesTask.call(TestCasesTask.java: 1281)[automation - 3.2 - SNAPSHOT.jar: 3.2 - SNAPSHOT]
at rogers.automation.core.execution.handlers.core.TestCasesTask.call(TestCasesTask.java: 81)[automation - 3.2 - SNAPSHOT.jar: 3.2 - SNAPSHOT]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java: 264)[ ? : ? ]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)[ ? : ? ]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java: 515)[ ? : ? ]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java: 264)[ ? : ? ]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)[ ? : ? ]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1128)[ ? : ? ]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 628)[ ? : ? ]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java: 834)[ ? : ? ]

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sikuli.script.Finder.(Ljava / awt / image / BufferedImage;) V
at solaris.stbinstall.automation.pageobjects.stb.MaestroAppPageSTBImpl.isImageVisible

Comment: After update JDK 8 to Open JDK 11, getting below issue while running the execution, tried with multiple version of Sikuli but still no luck

Comment: Any code to reproduce?  You're using SikuliX1, right?  Which version? https://raiman.github.io/SikuliX1/javadocs/org/sikuli/script/Finder.html

Comment: We were using 1.1.0 sikuli version, now I tried with 2.01. and 2.04 still getting same issue.

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should confirm if the version of selenium you have is compatible with the Sikuli jar version.
Besides, you can try and run Sikulix 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT from maven repository with one of the latest version of selenium.